# Cloud Functions for Firebase - get parent data from database trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is there a clean built in way of directly referencing the data value of the node above the database trigger? I understand I can get a parent ref which I could then query for the value, but if there was a more concise way of doing this that would be great thanks.

For clarity, I want to use a child node within an object as a trigger, and when it occurs get the value of the parent object directly, to avoid the function being invoked when other changes are made to the parent object like so:

```
const parentObject = {
 triggerValue: 'I want the function to be triggered only on writes to this path',
 parentValue: 'But I also want this value',
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.data.ref` and `event.data.adminRef` to navigate the database.  They are [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) objects and work exactly like they would if you were building a web app with Firebase on the client side.  So, if using the [parent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#parent) property to navigate up a level works fine for you, then just use that.  There's no additional special syntax.

Comment: OK thanks. I was just curios as to whether that data was kind of already there in the event object in the same way that event.data.val() is and wouldn't require an asynchronous read, but that's fine it makes sense for it not to be. Thanks

Comment: I see, yeah, the event only contains the data at the matched path and nothing above it.  That could be unnecessarily costly.

Comment: This has changed; this answre does not work anymore since 1.0.0.

Answer (score 9):

I've googled for this answer like six times and keep having to re-implement the solution.

Here's how to get the parent data, `post`, from a child attribute, `post.body`, that's changed:

```
exports.doStuff = functions.database
  .ref("/posts/{postId}/body")
  .onWrite(event => {
    return event.data.ref.parent.once("value").then(snap => {
      const post = snap.val();
      // do stuff with post here
    });
  });
```

Comment: Same here.  You are right from this post. Thank you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988494/cloud-functions-for-firebase-how-to-get-event-data-ref-parent-childxxx-val