# Cloud Functions for Firebase: How to get event.data.ref.parent.child("xxx").val?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a structure on Firebase like this:

```
members
 |- -kSjJSDFjl2DFc
          |- isDeleted: true
          |- gender: "male"
```

In my cloud function, I wrote:

```
exports.doMemberDeletion = functions.database.ref("/members/{memberId}/isDeleted").onWrite(event => {
    const isDeleted = event.data.val();

    if (isDeleted) {
        const gender = event.data.ref.parent.child("gender").val; // Error here
        console.log("Deleted a " + gender + " member");
    }
});
```

However, it gives error on `event.data.ref.parent.child().val`, please advise how to get the value in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [DeltaSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot) provided in the event data is for the matched location only.  Data higher in the tree or in siblings is not available.  If your member data is not so large that you're concerned about listening for changes to any of it, you could do this:

```
// listen one level higher in tree    
exports.doMemberDeletion = functions.database.ref("/members/{memberId}").onWrite(event => {
    const wasDeleted = event.data.previous.child('isDeleted').val();
    const isDeleted = event.data.current.child('isDeleted').val();

    if (!wasDeleted && isDeleted) {
        const gender = event.data.current.child('gender').val();
        console.log("Deleted a " + gender + " member");
    }
});
```

Your original approach also works, but requires a fetch of the gender data:

```
exports.doMemberDeletion = functions.database.ref("/members/{memberId}/isDeleted").onWrite(event => {
    const isDeleted = event.data.val();

    if (isDeleted) {
        // as noted in Jen Person's answer, use adminRef for unrestricted access
        return event.data.adminRef.parent.child('gender').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
           console.log("Deleted a " + snapshot.val() + " member");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, the 2nd approach doesn't work. snapshot.val() throws exception.

Comment: @Softhinker.com: I just copied and re-ran the code for 2nd approach.  I didn't get an error.  If you want to post the code that failed for you, I'll take a look.

Comment: if (isDeleted) {
        event.data.adminRef.parent.child("gender").once("value").then(gender => {
           console.log("Deleted a " + gender.val() + " member");
        });
    }


And the error log is:

TypeError: gender.val is not a function
    at exports.doMemberDeletion.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:57:43)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:35:20
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)

Comment: @Softhinker.com: Can't explain it.  I copy/pasted the code you provided in the comment and it ran without error.  Note that you are missing the `return` of the result of `once().then()`, but that shouldn't cause the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Does the user have permission to access the parent? If not, instead of event.data.ref, use event.data.adminRef to have unrestricted access to the database. See [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot) for more information.

Comment: In this case, event.data.ref and event.data.adminRef have the same access to the user executing the request, so it doesn't work when using snapshot.val() which throws exception.