# Get data from parent in Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to assign to a `const` the name value inside parent

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/likes')

.onWrite(event => {

    const name = event.parent.data.val().name; // this doesn't work. how do I properly get the name which is located in /messages/{pushId} ?
    });
```

[image: screenshot of the situation]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784744/cloud-functions-for-firebase-get-parent-data-from-database-trigger, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784744/cloud-functions-for-firebase-get-parent-data-from-database-trigger/45384501#45384501 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491967/firebase-get-parrent-of-parent-data-before-delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data), this is how you access data from another path:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/likes')
.onWrite(event => {
     return event.data.ref.parent.child('name').once('value').then(snapshot => {
        const name = snapshot.val();
    });
});
```

Comment: You sure this would work? The path is only listing to .../likes, how would it know the value for the key name?

Comment: Unfortunately, I get `TypeError: event.data.ref.parent.child(...).val is not a function`

Comment: @J.Doe dont confuse. i dont want key name!

Comment: Jen. Unfortunately, I get `TypeError: event.data.ref.parent.child(...).val is not a function` Thanks for your answer thogh

Comment: @Kolop copy and paste Jen's answer, it works. You need to add a **value listener** if you want to get the name data. You can't just call `event.data.ref.parent.child('name').val`.

Comment: @BradleyMackey okay. but what should I do if I want to get different `const`'s at once?

Comment: @BradleyMackey okay. but what should I do if I want to get different `const`'s at once?

Answer (score 0):

after version update

event <- (change, context)

event.data <-change.after

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/likes')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
 return change.after.ref.parent.child('name').once('value').then(snapshot => {
    const name = snapshot.val();
});
```

});